# ¿Cómo eliminar espacios en blanco/vacio que estan de mas en Angular?

Tags: angular

En Angular desde un`input text`por ejemplo si el usuario escribe:  `"La              Historia"`, con una funcion (o pipe o con lo que sea) quiero que me quite los espacios en blanco/vacios que estan de mas, para que quede de esta forma: "La Historia". En mi caso estoy intentando hacerlo con una función pero no da resultados.

Aca mi `formulario` en el `componente.html` donde intento llamar a la función `(blur)="cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(book.name)"` para que me retorne la cadena sin espacios en blanco/vacios que estan demas.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="createBook($event)">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-9 mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" 
            [(ngModel)]="book.name" placeholder="Nombre de libro"
            (blur)="cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(book.name)">
            <div *ngIf="form.get('name').errors && form.get('name').dirty">
                <p class="text-center mt-1" *ngIf="form.get('name').hasError('required')">Este campo es obligatorio!</p>
                <p class="text-center mt-1" *ngIf="form.get('name').hasError('maxlength')">El nombre es muy largo!</p>                             
            </div>                  
        </div>       
        <div class="text-center">
            <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Guardar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-white" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>                
        </div>  
    </div>               
</form>
```

Aca mi logica en el componente.ts

```js
book = {} as Book

constructor(){
  this.buildForm();
}


 buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.year)]],
      author: ['', [Validators.required]],
      category: ['', [Validators.required]],
      editorial: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2500)]],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
      price: [0, [Validators.required]],
      image: [''],
      state: [true]
    });
  }
  
cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(cadena: string){
   const cleanString = cadena.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
   console.log(cadena);
   return cleanString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de retornar la cadena corregida asígnala a la propiedad `book.name`.

```
cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(cadena: string){
       const cleanString = cadena.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
       this.book.name = cleanString;
    }
```

**Actualización**

Para que la función sea reusable se puede asignar su valor de retorno
desde la plantilla

```
cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(cadena: string){
       return cadena.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
 }
```

En el blur, asignar lo que retorna la función:

```
(blur)="book.name = cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(book.name)">
```

Comment: Gracias, de la forma que indicaste, si funciona, solo que mi función no es reutilizable, ya que solo sirviría para this.book.name, si quisiera utilizar esta funcion para otra propiedad ej: this.book.description,  no podria hacerlo.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para que la función sea reutilizable.

Comment: Perdon @Lobos, al compilar, me sale este error: src/app/admin/components/books/books.component.html:81:37 - error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.     

81                             (blur)="book.description = cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(book.description)"

Comment: Agregaste el return que se había quitado a la función?

Comment: Ahora si! gracias! habia olvidado el return, lo que pasa es que cree un servicio para reutilizar la funcion. y cuando desde el componente creaba la funcion para implementar al servicio, olvidaba poner el return, de esta forma funciona:

Comment: cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(cadena: string){
  const a = this.myValidationsService.cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(cadena);
    return a;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Mi consejo es que te suscribas a los cambios en el formulario:

```
ngOnInit() { //mejor aquí que en el constructor
  this.buildForm();
  this.form.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    const trimmed = newValue.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
    this.form.get('name').setValue(trimmed, {emitEvent: false});
    // emitEvent:false evita un loop infinito aquí
  });
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, tu forma de hacerlo tambien funciona, solo que si en el input hay espacios vacios en blanco de mas no los quita (visualmente) si los quita en book.name.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario `/\s{2,}/` para marcarle después de cuantos espacios en blanco, sólo aplica el operador `+` para iterar

```js
const text = "LA                         HISTORIA";
console.log( text );

const cleanText = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
console.log( cleanText );
```

Comment: gracias por responder, pero de tu forma no funciona.